# how to php echo individual column values of a result row from mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql

The below code works perfectly and gives me the "id" "firstname" and "lastname". What I want is to use a loop to echo all the field values in the result row without having to quote each column name like

```
$row["id"]
```

below is the working code

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

 // Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM MyGuests";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<br> id: ". $row["id"]. " - Name: ". $row["firstname"]. " " . 
$row["lastname"] . "<br>";
}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

any thoughts please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work..

```
while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
  $i=0;
  while($i<count($row)){
    echo $row[$i];
    $i++;
  }  
}
```

Comment: I got an error for this as below: Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@*****.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: Its not related to php code.. answer updated.. check again.. notice `fetch_array()`

Comment: I edited the code to be  like below;                                                               
       while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
    $i=0;
    while($i<count($row)){
      echo $row[$i];
      $i++;
    }  
  }                                                                                               but it still gives me only the first value "someuser".

Comment: I think the count($row) equals just one. I tried sizeof($row); and still the same result. Anymore thoughts?

Comment: try `print_r($row)` after `$i=0`.. and check if it having array of multiple key values..

Comment: after adding print_r($row) after $i=0 ,Now I get this:                                                                                      
     "Array
(
    [0] => someuser
    [Username] => someuser
)
someuser  
"

Comment: So there is only one data attribute in `$row` named `Username`.. So loop will only show whats in the array.. You need to check you query..

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake in the query. Now the query selects more than one field and your code works fine as is answered.

Comment: Good.. Learning is important :)

Answer (score 1):

just use a `foreach` loop inside while like this

```
foreach($row as $key=>$value){
 echo "<br> $key: ". $value. "<br>";
}
```

Comment: This answer gives me only the first column: " Username: Someuser"

Comment: as @Zaheer Attar suggested, I figured out the mistake in my query. Your code works just fine as is and outputs "Username: Someuser" and so on for all columns. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want to do is **automate the output of the name of each column with its value** (independent of the number of columns you get).

So do it like this :

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    foreach($result->fetch_assoc() as $row) { // browse each records
        foreach($row as $col => $value) { // browse each columns on a record
            echo "<br>$col: $value<br>";
        }
    }
} 
else {
    echo "no result";
}
```

Comment: Tried it, it produces <br> <br><br><br><br> continuously for the number of columns in the record.

Comment: it prints Array()Array()Array()Array()Array() continuously for the number of columns.

Comment: Thanks, but I got the answer.